# How to dynamically update sequence in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I need to update sequences in more then `26 tables` on various system

Right now I am doing `SELECT setval('auth_group_id_seq', max(id)) FROM auth_group;` for every table.

But is their a way where I can iterate over every table available in `\dt public.*` and then update the sequences.

I thought of doing something like this but got error instead `select table_name from tables where tables IN (\dt public.*);`

Comment: Can't we merge both the queries ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get every table in the public schema with this query:

```
 select tablename from pg_tables where schemaname='public';
```

[pg_tables doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/view-pg-tables.html)

To get all sequences per the public schema you can do this:

```
select cs.relname, nc.nspname
from pg_class cs 
join pg_namespace nc on cs.relnamespace = nc.oid
where cs.relkind='S' and nc.nspname='public';
```

[pg_class doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-class.html)

You should not need to link a sequence to a table in order to alter the sequence. Also consider the sequences are their own object and do not "belong" to a table in postgres. Sequences must be a unique name per schema, so as long as you alter the sequences you want per the correct schema this should do the trick.

Altering a sequence syntax:

`ALTER SEQUENCE serial RESTART WITH 105;`

[alter sequence doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altersequence.html)

A fast way to do these updates would be to dynamically generate the alter statements. However, this requires the value you are changing `maxvalue` to be the same on all sequences.

```
select 'alter sequence ' || nc.nspname || '.' || cs.relname || ' maxvalue  value_to_be_set;'
    from pg_class cs 
    join pg_namespace nc on cs.relnamespace = nc.oid
    where cs.relkind='S' and nc.nspname='public';
```

Would output something like this:

```
alter sequence public.sequence_1 maxvalue 5;
alter sequence public.sequence_2 maxvalue 5;
alter sequence public.sequence_3 maxvalue 5;
```

Comment: thanks for your reply can you tell me how do I get table name too with the same query. So that by executing single query I can update all the sequences

Comment: @vaibhavjain updated answer to help with your question in your comment

Comment: `id` is the max value which I need to update. I work on ORM,  I am not good with raw SQL. So I need to use `id` instead of `value_to_be_set` and this command will update all sequences ??

Comment: ok what is id? where does the id value come from a variable, a column? is it dynamic? This will generate code for you to execute.... so it will generate the actual alter statements then you can take and execute them.

Answer (score 1):

I recomend you to iterate over sequence:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_class WHERE relkind='S'
```