# Django app running on AWS elastic beanstalk cannot write to database

Tags: django, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Django app running on AWS elastic beanstalk. It was previously connected to a MySQL RDS instance. I have been through several steps to migrate the data from a MySQL instance to a PostgreSQL instance.
In brief I connected to the postgres instance and ran `python manage.py migrate`

I then ran `python manage.py sqlflush` and ran the resulting SQL commands

Then I imported a json fixture of content types from the MySQL db. I created the fixture (when connected to the MySQL db) with
`python manage.py dumpdata contenttypes --indent=4 --natural-foreign > contenttype.json`
and imported it into the PostgreSQL db with
`python manage.py loaddata contenttype.json`

The above preserves PKs and FKs

I then used AWS DMS to load the data from the MySQL instance to the PostgreSQL instance.

Using the Django app (e.g. through Django admin) all the data can be read from the Postgres instance. However, trying to post data to the database results in a 500 error.

Could this be a problem with security settings in AWS? It seems odd that I can read data from the DB but not post to it.

I've tried connecting to the DB using pgAdmin 4 with the same connection settings. I was able to use an INSERT statement to post to the database from there (but had to explicitly state the PK value)

**Update**

As suggested by Mark B the problem was Primary Keys. Many of the sequences in postgres had been reset to 1 as the current value. Finding the max value of the ID (PK) in each table and updating the corresponding sequence has got everything working. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35671493/how-to-dynamically-update-sequence-in-postgresql) on sequences and primary keys was useful.

Comment: "Could this be a problem with security settings in AWS?" No, absolutely not. There's something going on with your database user account.

Comment: Does database user account mean IAM policies?

Comment: No it means the account you enter in when you are connecting via pgAdmin. The account you use in the database connection settings in Django. The account that exists *inside* the PostgreSQL database server.

Comment: Looking at your question again, it seems you got a 500 error and didn't look further. 500 just means there was an error on the server and you need to look at the server logs to see what the actual error is. It could be that you are violating some sort of foreign key constraint or something in the database insert. You need to go to the Django logs to find the **actual** error message to see what you need to fix.

Comment: You are correct @MarkB it's a primary key constraint error. It seems all the pks have reset to 1 in the Django app. This might require a new question.